# Tagfield selection focus issue in ExtJS 6

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6, extjs6-classic

There is issue with `emptyText` in `Tagfield` focus in `ExtJS 6.`.Setting emptyText will break something in the picker focus management and keep the picker from being dismissed when the tagfield looses focus.

is there any workaround for this pop up fix ?

Please find fiddle [Glitch in tagfield when using emptyText config](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11ls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the problem persists even when the `emptyText` config is not set, indicating that this is a general issue with the focus of the picker. If you click on the text input, then click on the dropdown you can dismiss the picker. As a workaround, you can force the focus of the picker by listening to an `expand` event. The code below demonstrates this change:

```
{
    xtype: 'tagfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Select states',
    store: {
        type: 'states'
    },
    emptyText: 'Select...',
    displayField: 'state',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    filterPickList: true,
    queryMode: 'local',
    listeners: {
        expand: function (field) {
            field.getPicker().focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked your Solution , it working exactly..`Thanks for solution`
I have some small observation related to this fixe...
1) clicking outside tagfield dismissing drop down pop up , but still field remain focused
2) keyboard TAB traversing functionality do not work in that case

Comment: I don't seem to be experiencing your first problem. As for the second, the tab functionality seems to be breaking when you configure emptyText and isn't related to the solution I have provided. I'm not sure how to go about this, aside from adding a hack that listens to the tab keydown event and forcing the input focus.

Comment: I also observed some focus issue for input field as we are focusing picker..As so as you start typing something the text entry loses focus to the picker.